# How to remove Notification observer in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

Hi i am very new for ios and in my app i have created two view controllers

in my first view controllers i have added one button and when i click that button i am pushing second viewcontroller

in my second viewcontroller i have added NSNotificationCenter for checking app states this is working fine

my main problem is when i push back from second viewcontroller to first viewcontroller and i close the app once and opening again

then Here i wonder second view controller class NSLog statement is printing in this class

why this silly happening how can i stop this action please help me

### FirstViewcontroller:-

```
#import "FirstViewcontroller.h"

@interface FirstViewcontroller ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewcontroller

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {

    ViewController1 *details = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
        [self presentViewController:details animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

### SecondViewcontroller:-

```
#import "SecondViewcontroller.h"

@interface SecondViewcontroller ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewcontroller

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)appDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"did become active notification");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For removing observer of NSNotificationCenter in second screen you need to add following lines in viewwilldisappear method in second screen.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

You are not removing the observer from the notification center from what I can see. Thus, the instance you already popped is still alive and receives the notification.

Try removing the observer on popping the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in viewDidDisappear of second view controller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ReceiveAdNotification:) name:@"AnyName" object:nil];
```

For removing observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```